# Can't get the same img height in grid layout

Tags: css, grid, frontend

So I'm using a grid layout to display 4 pictures. The thing is that I can't get the pictures on the second row to be the same height:

[image]

My HTML is:

```
<section id="gallery">
    <h2>Gallery</h2>
    <div id="img-container">
        <img src="img/business1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="img/business2.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="img/business4.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="img/business5.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</section>
```

and my CSS:

```
#gallery #img-container {
    padding:20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

#gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

#gallery #img-container img:first-child {
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
}
```

Comment: How do you want to align them? it's aligned now, to the top, but aligned. Be more specific.

Comment: It might not be obvious, but if you look at the bottom row, I want them to be the same height

Comment: Oh ok, so, being same height is not the same as aligning them. Is it a posibility for your requirements to add a fixed height to the thumbs row? If so you can have images be 100% height (expect the first one), but you need a fixed height on the second row so the browser can do that calculation.

Comment: I need to avoid using a static height for the rows.

Comment: You can use vh or vw unit, it's fixed but not static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, use `max-content` (so the height is the max of the three images) for the thumbs row height and `align-self: stretch` for the images so they don't respect the aspect ratio:

```
#gallery #img-container {
    padding:20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto max-content;
}

#gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    align-self: stretch;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mvNyJG

Answer (score 1):

Add 'height="100%"' for the 3-nd and 4-th image:

```
<section id="gallery">
    <h2>Gallery</h2>
    <div id="img-container">
        <img src="img/business1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="img/business2.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="img/business4.jpg" alt="" height="100%">
        <img src="img/business5.jpg" alt="" height="100%">
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I was hoping for a solution without hardcoding the height